# Encoding with image/jpeg cause image saturation / wrong pixels

Tags: image, go, image-processing

I have been having this problem for some time: I'm creating a module to process images, one of my functions is to go through each pixel of an image and invert colors. The function returns the expected results when encoding .png images, but it "saturates" .jpeg/jpg images.

Example when processing a .png image (correct): https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r0Go.png

Example when processing a .jpeg image (error): https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7hNM.jpg

I was researching and the closest I found to my problem, although it's not an answer, is this issue from the Go repository: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23936

```golang
// InvertColors function

func InvertColors(img image.Image) image.Image {
    bounds := img.Bounds()
    width := bounds.Max.X
    height := bounds.Max.Y
    inverted := image.NewRGBA(bounds)

    for y := bounds.Min.Y; y < height; y++ {
        for x := bounds.Min.X; x < width; x++ {
            r, g, b, a := img.At(x, y).RGBA()
            c := color.RGBA{uint8(255 - r), uint8(255 - g), uint8(255 - b), uint8(a)}

            inverted.SetRGBA(x, y, c)
        }
    }

    return inverted
}

// main example
func main() {
    link := "https://i.imgur.com/n5hsdl4.jpg"
    img, err := GetImageFromURL(link)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    Encode(buf, img, "jpg")
    ioutil.WriteFile("temp.jpg", buf.Bytes(), 0666)

    invImg := InvertColors(img)
    buf = new(bytes.Buffer)
    Encode(buf, invImg, "jpg")
    ioutil.WriteFile("temp2.jpg", buf.Bytes(), 0666)
}

// GetImageFromURL 
func GetImageFromURL(link string) (image.Image, error) {
    _, format, err := ParseURL(link)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", link, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Required to make a request.
    req.Close = true
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "image/"+format)

    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    img, err := Decode(bytes.NewReader(b), format)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return img, nil
}

func ParseURL(link string) (u *url.URL, format string, err error) {
    u, err = url.Parse(link)
    if err != nil {
        return u, "", err
    }

    format = u.Path[len(u.Path)-4:]
    if strings.Contains(format, ".") {
        format = strings.Split(format, ".")[1]
    }

    if format != "png" && format != "jpg" && format != "jpeg" {
        return u, "", fmt.Errorf("Unsupported format: %s", format)
    }

    return u, format, nil
}

func Decode(r io.Reader, format string) (img image.Image, err error) {
    if format == "png" {
        img, err = png.Decode(r)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

    } else if format == "jpg" || format == "jpeg" {
        img, err = jpeg.Decode(r)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

    } else {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unsupported format: %s", format)
    }

    return img, nil
}
```

Comment: I don't speak *"Go"* at all, but you appear to be trying to get and set RGBA values on JPEG images in your `InvertColours()` function. But JPEG doesn't have an A channel - just RGB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two bugs in your code related to color-handling (the second of which is probably not relevant).

First, the `RGBA()` method returns 16-bit R, G, B, A, but you're treating them like 8-bit values.

Second, `color.RGBA` values are alpha-premultiplied, so the inverse of `(R, G, B, A)` is `(A-R, A-G, A-B, A`) and not `(MAX-R, MAX-G, MAX-B, A)`. This is probably not relevant, because it looks like your picture does not have any significant alpha.

One way to fix to your code is to replace this:

```
r, g, b, a := img.At(x, y).RGBA()
c := color.RGBA{uint8(255 - r), uint8(255 - g), uint8(255 - b), uint8(a)}
```

with this:

```
r, g, b, a := img.At(x, y).RGBA()
c := color.RGBA{uint8((a - r)>>8), uint8((a - g)>>8), uint8((a - b)>>8), uint8(a>>8)}
```

(Note, that you may find that first converting your image to `image.NRGBA` (if it's not already) and then iterating over underlying byte slice that stores the (non-alpha-premultiplied) RGBA channels for the image is much faster than using the more abstract interfaces provided by the `image` and `color` packages.)

Comment: Interesting and enlightening answer for someone who isn't familiar with *"Go"*. How does it handle 32-bit per sample greyscale images? Or images with 32-bit Red + 32-bit Green + 32-bit Blue samples?

Comment: @MarkSetchell A defect of the stdlib color and image packages are that their methods use 16-bit-per-channel colors, bounded by 0 and 0xffff. You can easily make any image format you like (eg: floating point channels), but if you give them to a function that accesses the image through the std api, then you'll lose information. For example: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/DexterLB/traytor/hdrimage . Background reading from the go blog: https://go.dev/blog/image

Comment: Many thanks for making time to reply - much appreciated.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! The changes worked, I'll be more careful next time. I already knew that working over the underlying byte slice is faster, but I wanted to keep it simple until I fixed the bug.